# Springboot Application startup failed due to OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (Unable to create entityManagerFactory Bean)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We are using spring boot version 2.1.3 with sprintboot jpa started.

Application is failing at startup with logs:

> Injecting ScanOptions
>   [org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.StandardScanOptions@78d49939]
>   into BootstrapContext; was
>   [org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.StandardScanOptions@21f27bb5]
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Heap memory: 512 MB.

Hibernate properties :

```
spring.jpa:
database: ORACLE
show-sql: true
generate-ddl: false
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: none
properties:
  hibernate:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    id:
      new_generator_mappings: true
    show_sql: false
    connection:
      autocommit: true
      release_mode: after_transaction
```

Using ojdbc7.

We are getting this issue intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

This error is purely related to heap memory. After increasing heap memory at startup, It worked well.